# Html multiple select options to shopping cart via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/o39chw9x/

I have multiple select boxes in my html like this:

```
<select class=".form-bestel.select" name="product">
    <option value="0">Melk, vol (0,5l)</option>
    <option value="1">Melk, vol (1l) </option>
    <option value="2">Melk, mager (1l) </option>
</select>

<select class=".form-bestel.select" name="product">
    <option value="3">Boter (250g)</option>
    <option value="4">Boter (500g)</option>
    <option value="5">Boter (1kg)</option>
    <option value="6">Kruidenboter (125g)</option>
    <option value="7">Kruidenboter (1kg)</option>
</select>
```

under each select box is a input field for the amount:

```
<input class=".form-bestel" name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="Aantal" type="number" min="0" style="width: 100%;heigt:100%;margin-bottom: 5px;"> </input>
```

under that input field is a button:

```
<a href="#0" class="cd-add-to-cart" style="margin-bottom: 40px; margin-top: 30px;">Voeg toe</a>
```

That button is connected with javascript. When it's clicked following function runs:

```
addToCartBtn.on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    addToCart($(this));
});
```

then:

```
function addToCart(trigger) {
    var cartIsEmpty = cartWrapper.hasClass('empty');
    //update cart product list
    addProduct();
    //update number of items 
    updateCartCount(cartIsEmpty);
    //update total price
    updateCartTotal(trigger.data('price'), true);
    //show cart
    cartWrapper.removeClass('empty');
}
```

then:

```
function addProduct() {
    //var productid = document.getElementById('product').value;
    var productid = 4;
    var product = products[productid];

    var price = prices[document.getElementById('product').value];
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
}
```

NOTE: I know there are no id's product or amount in the html. That's my problem:

How can i get the chosen value from 2 or more different html select boxes if i can't give them a same id. How can I best pass it through the first js-function I call?

What I want to get is, when i select the right thing and press on the button "Voeg toe" it appears in my shopping cart. So the JS function need to know which one I selected and what the integer was in the input..

Comment: the `value` attribute on the option tag is the key

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal the value of the select? or the value of the options?

Comment: Well, the value of select is the value of the option. But the attribute is placed on options only. Google it up

Answer (score 1):

This is a common pattern for repeating components within a page.

Your demo is filled with a lot of irrelevant code so I will show you a simplified case

You want to isolate the product instance using a traverse up fom the button, and them look inside that instance for the input values

```
$('.cd-add-to-cart').on('click', function(e){
  // isolate instance
   var $row = $(this).parent(),
       // look inside instance for values
       qty = $row.find('input').val(),
       type = $row.find('select').val(); 

      // do something with these values
});
```